# What does the "set" keyword mean in ruby?

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I'm going through the capistrano handbook

https://github.com/leehambley/capistrano-handbook/blob/master/index.markdown

And see the keyword "set" appear

```
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
```

Does set in this example set the symbol `:deploy_via` to `:remote_cache`?

Comment: `set` is not ruby keyword is `capistrano` command

Answer (score 6):

That's not a keyword in standard Ruby. It's an example of an element in a Domain Specific Language (DSL).

Basically, a DSL allows you to work at a higher level of abstraction by providing more targeted constructs than a general-purpose language like Ruby. The "set" here is an example of this. It's probably just a function in Ruby that you're actually calling, but when you use it, it feels more like a language construct in its own right. Ruby is particularly good at writing DSLs

As for what this does in Capistrano, I have no idea, I've never used Capistrano. :)

Answer (score 6):

`set` is not ruby keyword in `capistrano` command

from capistrano source

```
 def set(key, value)
   @properties[key] = value
 end
```

Answer (score 3):

`set` has no particular meaning in Ruby. In fact, it's not a Ruby keyword, it's a Capistrano command, part of the Capistrano DSL.

Technically speaking, it's a Ruby method. You can see the [method definition](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/v3.0.1/lib/capistrano/configuration.rb#L19-L21).

```
def set(key, value)
  config[key] = value
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The other guys stole my thunder, but [here](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-DSL-Configuration-Variables-Set) is a discussion of `set` within the context of the Capistrano DSL:

> "*This method is the primary way of defining variables that can be accessed anywhere within a Capistrano configuration. It allows you to set both immediate and deferred variables, depending on whether or not you used a block to define the variable.*"

Answer (score 0):

It could be referred to as a 'bareword' but not a *[keyword](http://www.ruby-doc.org/search.html?cx=011815814100681837392%3Awnccv6st5qk&q=keywords&sa=Search&cof=FORID%3A9)*, as that is how Ruby names the collection of "Reserved Words" for the language.  As such, it is either a variable or a method name, due to the fact that it is not prepended with @ or $ or @@ and is not capitalized.

It is in fact just a method.